# using jquery in two usercontrol in the same page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two user control in my page uc1 and uc2. I want to make sure that the js function inside these two user control fire when the document is ready.

When I am using '$(document).ready({function(){//something});' in both the user control only the function of the first user control is loading. the function for the second user control was not called.

Can't I use '(document).ready' in two different user control in the same page?
If not then how can I make sure that the respective methods are called only when the document is ready?

Comment: your IE browser should detect a javascript error. possibly, you named a function twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any number of functions to `$(document).ready`, and they [should all execute](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready).

Perhaps the 2nd script gives an error before it can do what it's supposed to do?  Consider installing [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and open your website in FireFox.

Comment: when i removed the first user control. the function inside the second user control is getting called.

Comment: @syd: Possibly the first user control adds functions or variables to the global namespace that conflict with the second user control?

Answer (score 0):

you can do any of the below

**1**

structure of your .ascx file

```
    //Demo control
    Name : <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" />
```

**Javascript**

```
//this is DOM ready
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#'+<%=txtName.ClientID%>).doSomething();
});
```

**2**
or other way

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" CssClass="myClass" />

add this code the page that holds these controls

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.myClass').DOSomeThing();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My first bet would go for checking duplicate namings of functions, variables that has same name. I woukd also figure out if i can put functionality to tha masterpage (or a new, if its specifik). This would simplify error tracing. I also recommend firebug andhttpwatch for js debugging.  Now your sample gaves a small indication that document.ready is the only method call u are using in each user  control?

Comment: I would also say, dont link jquery.js into each user control!